# Problems with using ncp inside my grunt plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

for some reasons, I´m doing a custom grunt plugin for copy some specific directories. The idea for the plugin is to pass a parameter from console with the source path.

I´m using ncp module to copy directories but inside my grunt plugin doesn´t work (If I use node to execute the code, all works fine... the directories are created... the files and directories and files are copied).

It doesn´t do anything... no ok console message... no error console message... I´ve being debugging inside the ncp code and I´ve discovered that the function fs.lstat it doesn´t work.

I´ve reviewed that the source path and the destination path are ok... so... I don´t know... maybe is a nonsense but I can´t find it ;)

You can see both examples via Gist:

- [Using Node](https://gist.github.com/felixzapata/7159552): when the task is completed, show me the "done!" message.
- [Using Grunt](https://gist.github.com/felixzapata/7159513): it doesn´t do anything... only create the destination directory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[I´ve found a solution that its works for my intentions](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib/issues/82). I´d have liked to use grunt copy task inside of my plugin but I couldn´t config the correct values manually.